# Can I startActivityForResult from a Chrome web page on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

On an android phone: I would like my webpage to call my app. I am currently using https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents .

I would then like my native app to return a value back to the webpage that called it.
Is there anything like [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) that I can call from my webpage so that Android returns the result from my app to my webpage?

I could obviously redirect back to my webpage using a new browser intent with the return values encoded as query parameters, however that would force me to reload my webpage again in another browser tab (possibly in a different browser as well, if the user has more than one web browser installed on their android device). I would much rather return the value to the same web page that launched the native app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot do this. The browser launches the App with an `Intent` as "fire and forget". There is no way to call `startActivityForResult()` and no way to return anything. You would need to use the redirect technique, or you need to use a completely different mechanism.